GUI Problems on Kali Linux (no wallpaper, folders, can't right click, no top bars) installed on VMware Fusion running on a Apple Silicon (MacBook M2)
I downloaded the last Kali Linux for Apple Silicon (MacBook M2) and installed it on VMware Fusion.
After installation everything was okay. Then, I run the command sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade to get everything up to date.
But after reboot I only get the login screen's wallpaper instead of the main desktop's wallpaper, no folders on the desktop screen, can't select anything or do right click.
And if I open terminal or another folder through the top menu bar, the top tab with the "close, maximize and minimize" doesn't appear.
Already tried to reinstall Kali but this always happens after reboot the system.



Kali is for advanced researchers only. It is not designed as a desktop environment. Use another more mainstream version. Any utility that Kali has will also be available elsewhere.

I encountered a similar issue with kali-linux-2024-3-vmware-amd64 on VMware Workstation 17 Pro.
Simply run the following command:
sudo apt full-upgrade

Then restart the virtual machine, and everything should be back to normal.
This problem occurs because some packages are not updated when using sudo apt upgrade.
